# Select equivalent rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need to find out if I have equivalent rows and how many are they.
My table structure looks like this:

```
id     foreign_key     num1     num2
1           1            1       2 
2           1            3       3
3           2            1       2
4           2            3       3
5           9            8       7
--          --           --      --
```

I need an output that says I have 1 (the foreign_key) is equal to 2 (group by)
since they have 1  2 and 3  3

Comment: Please take time, format your question. Say this is the input and this should be the output because of blah blah..

Comment: *Equivalent rows* means *rows with the same `foreign_key`*?

Answer (score 0):

```
select foreign_key, count(*) as number 
from tablename 
group by foreign_key
```